# How to make a table generator using prompt()?

Tags: javascript, html-table, prompt

I need to make a table generator using the `prompt()`, `var`, `parseInt`, `isNaN` and `document.write` in Javascript. The user would be prompted to input the number of rows and then the number of columns.

This is what I wrote so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var row;
var col;
do
{
row = prompt("How many rows?");
}
while (isNaN(row))
do
{
col = prompt("How many columns?");
}
while (isNaN(col))

document.write('<table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">');
for(i = 0; i < row; i++)
{
   document.write('<tr>');
   document.write("<td>"+i+"</td>");
   document.write('</tr>');
}

document.write('</table>');
</script>
```

I don't know how to make the number of:

```
"document.write("<td>"+i+"</td>");"
```

depend on the variable "col".

I also don't know how to use `parseInt` or `isNaN` to make sure the numbers input range from 1 to 10. Please go easy on me, I'm a beginner.

Comment: is this a homework???? Why do you have to use only those methods?

Comment: Use a nested loop to generate the appropriate number of columns. Use `parseInt` when you need to [extract an integer from a string value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Comment: I think homework question are ok if there a real problem exist. Please let me know about you @moon.

Comment: Maybe javascript wont able to write invalid html. So init you table into a variable then write it at once. This way will cause you performance problem also

Comment: @TimMedora How can I use a nested loop to generate the number of columns? I really have no idea..

Comment: Here's one way: http://jsfiddle.net/8HWRR/